# Linux command behaves strangely in shell command line

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

Please take a look at below commands:

```
administrator@ubuntu:~/usp$ cat file
c
b
a
administrator@ubuntu:~/usp$ x="cat file | sort"
administrator@ubuntu:~/usp$ $x
c
b
a
cat: |: 没有那个文件或目录
cat: sort: 没有那个文件或目录
```

My question is why the output of $x is not:

```
a
b
c
```

Dose the double quotes change the behavior of command `cat file | sort`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's happening is that `$x` is executed as a single command. The shell isn't "re-parsing" the contents of `$x`, and so it's not, in particular, setting up redirection and spawning `sort`.

What happens is that  `cat` gets handed three arguments: `file`, `|` and `sort`. You don't have a file named `|` or `sort` in that directory, so `cat` can't open them. (I'm guessing that what the error says anyway<sup>1</sup>.)

You could get the result you expect by running:

```
eval "$x"
```

I'd avoid using `eval` if you can though, it [can be dangerous](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

<sub><sup>1</sup>Prefix your commands with `LC_ALL=` to get English error messages before asking for help on international sites.

e.g. `LC_ALL= $x`.</sub>

Comment: This is indeed what the error messages say (no such file or directory).

Comment: Thanks @Mat and @EOL. I want to use a variable in `until` command like `until $var` to reduce code lines, because in different situations, the `until` command statement varies. In one of the situations, I need to do the assignment like `var="command1 | command2"`. Now it doesn't work. Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: @Wenhao Yang: you should ask a new question for that, but be sure to include enough details because that looks a bit strange. Can't you use a function instead of a variable?

Comment: @WenhaoYang: before posting another question, check [BashFAQ #50:I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) to see if it covers what you need.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson for giving such important information. It gives me details that I can't find in my shell tutorial. I will learn it before I post a new question. Thanks Mat for your new way.

Comment: @WenhaoYang: Side note: I would not recommend learning and using a shell language to do anything beyond very basic things (running a sequence of commands, piping, redirecting output,…). In fact, more complex operations are much more conveniently handled by a more modern scripting language like Python or Perl (and maybe Ruby, but I have no experience with it).

Comment: @EOL: These days I am self-learning Linux programming. Just finishing learning Linux C and interface, now I move to basic Linux shell programming. Thanks for your kind reminder.